# Prevent a player from using creature type?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a card that has an ability to the effect of "Choose a creature type. Creatures of that type cannot be summoned."? I feel like I would have found something on it if there was, seeing as it counters A LOT of decks, but I'd like to get confirmation.

Comment: The modern wording of such a card would probably be something like "Choose a creature type. Creature spells of that type cannot be cast."

Answer (score 9):

That specific effect does not exist. However, there are some cards with effects that are probably less powerful, but still can do significant damage to a tribal deck:

- [An-Zerrin Ruins](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAn-Zerrin%20Ruins%5d) prevents creatures of a chosen type from untapping.
- [Circle of Solace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCircle%20of%20Solace%5d) allows you to prevent damage from creatures of a chosen type.
- [Engineered Plague](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEngineered%20Plague%5d) decreases the power and toughness of creatures of a chosen type. [Outbreak](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOutbreak%5d) has a similar effect, but just for one turn.
- [Tsabo's Decree](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTsabo%27s%5d%2b%5bDecree%5d) destroys creatures of a chosen type, and also makes your opponent discard creature cards of that type.

Comment: I had [Tivadar's Crusade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=159829) in a white deck (sideboard) just because one player in my group at college loved his goblin deck.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no card that prevents creature types from being played. The closest card (prevention wise) would be [Iona, Shield of Emeria](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIona%2c%20Shield%20of%20Emeria%5d), which prevents your opponents from playing a color. This would do quite a bit of damage to a tribal deck, since most tribes favor a color (goblins are red, merfolk are blue, elves are green etc)